# Is it appropriate to comment at users who aren't yet involved in the Q&A to get them involved?

Tags: discussion, comments, users, comment-replies

When answering a question:  Is it appropriate to @-notify another user whom you know has experience related to the question, in the comments?

For example, I answer a question using one particular method, knowing that a few other users might have some valuable information to weigh in, but aren't currently involved in the Q&A.  Is it OK to address them in a comment to my answer, to get their perspective?

It's not about playing favorites, and I wouldn't want to promote certain users over others.  If anything, it would prompt them to write an answer that is a better solution than the one I created or at least a different approach.

Chances are pretty good they will see the post without me notifying them, but the comment would welcome their critiques of my answer.

I wouldn't want to do this often and definitely can see it getting out of hand if everyone goes around asking their buddies to answer questions.  That's not the intention, but might be an unwanted side effect or trend that could develop.

Comment: Unless they've interacted on the post, a comment referencing them won't notify them.  It'd be useless.

Comment: You can't tag them *anyway* so this discussion is moot. You can only tag authors, those that have already commented, and editors (the latter are not included in the auto-completion).

Comment: Probably for the reasons I mentioned in the bottom of my question.  Thanks.  that's what I was wondering.

Comment: There is a central FAQ on MSE: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) that explains this in detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a central FAQ on MSE: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) that explains this in detail, but in short, this is not something you can even *do*.

Only people *already* involved with a post can be pinged in comments. Comment replies can only notify:

- The author of the post you are commenting on
- Anyone that has already commented on the post
- Anyone that has edited the post. Their names won't appear in the auto-completion however.

Comment: As an aside, there was once a feature-request to allow irritating (disguised as inviting) high-rep users who might be able to answer ones question. Cannot find it anymore though.